# How to put the command to remove duplicate lines in my awk script?

Tags: csv, awk, cgi

I create a CGI in bash/html.

My awk script looks like :

```
echo "<p><h2>FRAME : $test</h2></p>"

echo "<table>"
for fn in /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/*;
do
echo "<td>"
echo "<PRE>"

awk -F',|;' -v test="$test" '
     NR==1 { 
        split(FILENAME ,a,"[-.]");
      }
      $0 ~ test {
          if(!header++){
              print "DATE ========================== : " a[4] 
          }
          print ""
          print "LPARS :" $2
          print "RAM : " $5
          print "CPU 1 : " $6
          print "CPU 2 : " $7
          print "" 
          print ""
      }' $fn;



echo "</PRE>"
echo "</td>"
done
echo "</table>"
```

This script allow to analyze 276 csv files that looks like :

```
MO2PPC20;mo2vio20b;Running;VIOS 2.2.5.20;7;1.0;2;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;192
MO2PPC20;mo2vio20a;Running;VIOS 2.2.5.20;7;1.0;2;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;192
MO2PPC21;mplaix0311;Running;AIX 7.1 7100-05-02-1832;35;0.6;4;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;64
MO2PPC21;miaibv194;Running;AIX 6.1 6100-09-11-1810;11;0.2;1;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;64
MO2PPC21;mplaix0032;Running;AIX 6.1 6100-09-11-1810;105;4.0;11;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;128
MO2PPC21;mplaix0190;Running;Unknown;243;4.9;30;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;128
MO2PPC21;mo2vio21b;Running;VIOS 2.2.6.10;6;1.5;3;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;192
MO2PPC21;miaibv238;Running;AIX 7.1 7100-05-02-1810;10;0.5;1;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;64
MO2PPC21;mo2vio21a;Running;VIOS 2.2.6.10;6;1.5;3;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;192
MO2PPC21;miaibv193;Running;AIX 6.1 6100-09-11-1810;12;0.2;1;DefaultPool;shared;uncap;64
MO1PPC17;miaibe03;Running;AIX 5.2 5200-10-08-0930;25;null;3;null;ded;share_idle_procs;null
MO1PPC17;miaiba12;Running;AIX 5.2 5200-10-08-0930;17;null;2;null;ded;share_idle_procs;null
MO1PPC17;miaibf03;Running;AIX 5.2 5200-10-08-0930;30;null;3;null;ded;share_idle_procs;null
MO1PPC17;miaibc05;Running;AIX 5.2 5200-10-08-0930;40;null;2;null;ded;share_idle_procs;null
```

And to display them in my CGI like this :
[image]

The numbers of columns is equal at the number of csv to analyze.

As you can see in the screenshot, some lines are sometimes the same in each csv files

The idea is to delete the lines that are the same in all my csv files.

I know the awk command :

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

But this command needs a file to be achieved.

Do you think it's possible to put this command in my awk script ?

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by "But this command needs a file to be achieved". `awk` reads lines of data, and those lines can be provided by a filename after the script, a redirection before or after the script and by a pipeline. i.e. `awk '!a[$0]++' file` OR `awk '!a[$0]++' < file` OR `<file awk '!a[$0]++'` OR `echo "stuff" | awk '!a[$0]++'`. Great question, keep posting! Good luck.

Comment: Hello ! :) I mean that the command should look like ` awk '!a[$0]++' file.txt`. But in my case, I can't create one big file and apply the command. That is why I would like to put it in my awk script.

Comment: Hm.. still not clear to me. do you mean `awk -f myAwkScript file.txt`? Just create your script file and call it like that. Or 1) include correct path at top with `#!/bin/awk -f` 2) make it executable with `chmod +x myAwkScript` and then just run it like `./myAwkScript file.txt`. All the other options `< file` etc still apply to this form. Good luck.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm french so I don't speak english very well ( and I think this is why you having trouble to understand ). In brief, the command `awk '!a[$0]++'` is applicable only like that `awk '!a[$0]++ file.txt`, or something like this, right ? I can't do that because I have 276 files.. I can't do `awk '!a[$0]++' 1.csv ... 276.csv`, that is why I would like to use it inside my awk script... It's possible that I fail to understand how this command works.

Comment: OK, that is helpful explanation (and please don't worry about your language skills, I have no facility with any language besides the `c` and shell scripting languages ;-) ). Yes, you can supply multiple files on the command line, but there are limits. if you really "only" have 276 files (and they have short names), you should be able to `cd /path/to/data ; awk '!a[$0]++' *.csv > all ; mv all all.csv` . If your filenames are really long, (or you have more than 2000 files) you might reach the limit of what your shell will process on one cmd line. ....

Comment: And to make things really bullet proof, you can use a cmd designed specifically to handle "too many arguments" problem, `xargs`. so you can do something like `find /path/to/data -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 awkScript {} >> all`. `xargs` will make sure all files a processes as efficiently as possible. `man xargs` for lots of options that can make things run faster. (Maybe not in this case, if you reall need `>> all` (you would have to experiment). Search here for `[bash] xargs` for many good Q/A to give you more ideas how to use it (if you need it!). Good luck!

Comment: That looks exactly like the script I created for you or someone else in a different question but being used incorrectly. Please add the links to the previous questions that you built your current script from so we have that context available.

Answer (score 1):

Read all files at once with awk and add condition :

```
awk -F',|;' -v test="$test" '
 BEGIN{
    print "<table>"
 }
 FNR==1 {
    if(close_tag++){
            print "</PRE>"
            print "<td>"
    }
    print "<td>"
    print "<PRE>"
    split(FILENAME ,a,"[-.]");
  }
  ($0 ~ test) && (!dup[$0]++) {
      if(!header++){
          print "DATE ========================== : " a[4] 
      }
      print ""
      print "LPARS :" $2
      print "RAM : " $5
      print "CPU 1 : " $6
      print "CPU 2 : " $7
      print "" 
      print ""
  }
  END{
      print "</PRE>"
      print "</td>"
      print "</table>"
  }' /var/www/cgi-bin/LPAR_MAP/*
```

Comment: Hello ! If I try your proposition, I have this result :
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/32/3/1565183574-test4.png

There is a problem somewhere but I don't know where... Thank you anyway for your help ! :)

Comment: Edited, you need to remove the `for` loop and read all files at once with `awk`.

Comment: That would delete lines that appear for the 2nd and subsequent times across all files, the OP wants to delete lines that appear 1 or more times across all 3 files.

Comment: If I understand the OPs needs correctly then the condition would need to be something like `!(file1[$0] && file2[$0] && file3[$0])` with some other code to populate those arrays per input file rather than `!dup[$0]++` and that'd mean you have to read all files twice - once to identify the blocks that are common across all input files and then again to process all blocks.